# What happens when callback occured after activity is being closed

Tags: android, callback

Lets say im im in some activity, and call to some background operation

```
SomeOperation someOperation = new SomeOperation();
someOperation.setOnOperationFinishListener(new OnOperationFinishListener(
{
   public void onOperationFinish()
   {
     // do some stuff
   }

});
someOperation.start();
```

Will it be a problem if I exit the activity before the operation finish?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Your code makes no sense. Also FYI an operation is a function.. not an object. So the name makes no sense. Please write it in a legible programming format.

Comment: The simple answer is the callback won't happen and whatever is attempting to make the callback will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo code seems a bit confusing. But my guess would be that it would depend on exactly what background operation you're doing. If you're grabbing files off a server or something of the sort, then you exit the activity before the operation gets a chance to fully complete it's task..this shouldn't be much of an issue. But again, depends on what exactly you're trying to do here.